# Does df(a)/du make sense or should it be df(a)/da?

Tags: calculus

In a [chapter](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/deep-learning-from/9781492041405/ch01.html) of a computing book I am reading where the author introduces the derivative he uses the following formula without explanation of the variable u

$$
\frac{{df(a)}}{{du}} = \lim_{{\Delta \to 0}} \frac{{f(a+\Delta) - f(a-\Delta)}}{{2 \times \Delta}}
$$

then later goes on to use the following while explaining the chain rule
$$
\frac{df_{2}}{du}(x) = \frac{df_{2}}{du}(f_{1}(x)) \times \frac{df_{1}}{du}(x)
$$
and stating "where u is simply a dummy variable representing the input to a function."

My understanding is that in the first equation since 'a' is specified as the input to 'f' that 'du' should actually be 'da', and as a result the second is just plain wrong.

Is the author abusing notation or am I confused about something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $u$ is the independent variable. Therefore, the LHS
is actually $f'(a)=\frac{df}{du}\mid_{u=a}$. That is, the derivative
of $f$ evaulated at $a$.

Comment: I agree, as I would rather call that copy of $u$ an independent variable than a dummy variable per se.